# Case sensitivity in rspec mysql vs rails controller

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rspec, case-sensitive

I have a test for an index that filters on last name, the test is passing:

```
it "finds transactions with a given customer last_name" do
  customer = create :customer, last_name: "Merp"
  t2 = create :transaction, location_id: @location.id
  t1 = create :transaction, location_id: @location.id, customer_id: customer.id
  get :index, last_name: "merp"
  assigns(:transactions).should eq [t1]
end
```

Here is the important part of the controller for this question:

```
# => @filter = {:customers=>{:last_name=>"merp"}}
# => @joins = [:customer]
@transactions = Transaction
  .joins(@joins)
  .where(@filter)
```

But when I do the test manually in a development environment, it only returns for case sensitive matches (notice the test is not a case match).

Why am I getting a passing test using non-case-sensitive searching while having the action fail on non-case-sensitive searches when I actually use the page?

Comment: Are you using the same kind of database for both test and development? i.e. MySQL vs SQLite?